# How to limit the size of Files of type dropdown in Application.FileDialog()?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code, but when it comes to selecting the file type (which should only be limited to PDF) the dropdown box is more than one entry big and so looks like this:

[image: Dropdown filter].

How can I alter the appearance so that it's the size for only one entry? I'm sure I've seen it done before elsewhere.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

 Dim f    As Object

 Dim g

 Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

 Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
 With f
 .Filters.Clear
 .Title = "Select Drawing"
 .Filters.Add "PDF Documents", "*.pdf"
 .FilterIndex = 1
 .AllowMultiSelect = False
 End With

If f.Show = 0 Then

Exit Sub

Else

from = f.SelectedItems(1)


Me.AcroPDF4.LoadFile "from"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can alter the size of that dropdown with `FileDialog`, perhaps in the API case you could, having said that it's not really necessary, also if you only have one entry, user's won't even need to drop that box down : )

Answer (score -1):

Looks perfect, brotha.  Here's a step-by-step guide with a pic of the dialog box, and it's only showing XLS files.  Your code looks the same as his (more or less).

http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s209/type-filedialog.htm